# UIView textured uitableview cell?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview

I am trying to emulate the texture that is used on these tableview cells

http://pixelsbyrick.com/blog/alarmik.html

I was wondering if apple allowed us to create a background texture layer then super impose a Color onto of it. This appears to be a metallic texture.

Comment: I'm looking at the article you linked to but where is the "texture"?

Comment: You have look close it looks sorta like a matte finish on each of the ui table view cells.

Comment: http://pixelsbyrick.com/static/images/blog/alarmik/alarmik5.png look at this picture it's a bit more evident close up

Comment: All I see is a solid color with a mild gradient.

Comment: Are you using a retina display?  if you zoom in it looks like it was spray painted on a bumpy ish surface almost like a bump map. Thats what I mean by texture.

Comment: Well, I've given my answer. Send me the retina display if you need more help. :))))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand what you mean by "texture". The background view of an UITableViewCell can be an image view. Thus, you could start with an appropriate image. You can "tint" the image in various ways using a CIFilter, so you could use the same effect in different colors pretty easily. Alternatively, a UITableViewCell can have a background color, or you can supply a background view with a background color - and a color can be a "pattern" (a repeated tile, in effect).

Comment: I guess there isn't a bumpmap like way todo this Thanks!

Comment: Well, you could use OpenGL, but that's a little heavyweight for this sort of thing, and I don't believe it's what the original model is doing. Also note (I should have said this in my answer) that you can start with a decent image and tint it using CIFilter.

Comment: I think I'd better add mention of CIFilter to my answer.

Comment: yeah I think I can apply an image filter on that color and hope to get a similar effect

Comment: Check out the CIGlassDistortion filter! It looks pretty awesome.